# Binary search tree add function

Tags: c, binary-tree

I'm trying to build functions for a binary tree, and I'm running into trouble with `_addNode()`.

I have my `Node` and `BSTree` structs below:

```
struct Node {
    TYPE         val;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

struct BSTree {
    struct Node *root;
    int          cnt;
};
```

I also have the init, create new tree, size, and is empty functions:

```
void initBSTree(struct BSTree *tree)
{
    tree->cnt  = 0;
    tree->root = 0;
}

struct BSTree*  newBSTree()
{
    struct BSTree *tree = (struct BSTree *)malloc(sizeof(struct BSTree));
    assert(tree != 0);

    initBSTree(tree);
    return tree;
}

int isEmptyBSTree(struct BSTree *tree) { return (tree->cnt == 0); }

int sizeBSTree(struct BSTree *tree) { return tree->cnt; }
```

But my add function is the one that's giving me trouble:

```
struct Node *_addNode(struct Node *cur, TYPE val) {
    struct Node* newNode;
    //base case
    if(cur == 0)  {
        newNode = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        assert(newNode !=0);
        newNode->val = val;
        newNode->left = 0;
        newNode->right = 0;
        return newNode;
    }
    //recursive case
    if(val < cur->val)  {
        cur->left = _addNode(cur->left,val);
    }
    else if(val > cur->val) {
        cur->right = _addNode(cur->right, val);
    }
    return cur;
}

void addBSTree(struct BSTree *tree, TYPE val)
{
    tree->root = _addNode(tree->root, val);
    tree->cnt++;
}
```

I define TYPE like: `# define TYPE void*` and I'm trying to test it using the following compare function:

```
struct data {
    int number;
    char *name;
};

int compare(TYPE left, TYPE right) {
    struct data *leftD;
    leftD = (struct data*)left;
    struct data *rightD;
    rightD = (struct data*)right;
    if (leftD->number < rightD->number) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (leftD->number > rightD->number) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When testing, adding a right node break the compare function since I'm pretty sure it's trying to compare to a right node that doesn't exist.  I'm not totally sure what the problem is, but I'm almost positive it's in my add node function and not the compare function.

My test (It breaks on test 3):

```
void testAddNode() {
    struct BSTree *tree = newBSTree();

    struct data myData1,  myData2,  myData3,  myData4;

    myData1.number = 50;
    myData1.name = "rooty";
    addBSTree(tree, &myData1);
    //check the root node
    if (compare(tree->root->val, (TYPE *) &myData1) != 0) {
        printf("addNode() test: FAIL to insert 50 as root\n");
        return;
    }
    //check the tree->cnt value after adding a node to the tree
    else if (tree->cnt != 1) {
        printf("addNode() test: FAIL to increase count when inserting 50 as root\n");
        return;
    }
    else printf("addNode() test: PASS when adding 50 as root\n");


    myData2.number = 13;
    myData2.name = "lefty";
    addBSTree(tree, &myData2);

    //check the position of the second element that is added to the BST tree
    if (compare(tree->root->left->val, (TYPE *) &myData2) != 0) {
        printf("addNode() test: FAIL to insert 13 as left child of root\n");
        return;
    }
    else if (tree->cnt != 2) {
        printf("addNode() test: FAIL to increase count when inserting 13 as left of root\n");
        return;
    }
    else printf("addNode() test: PASS when adding 13 as left of root\n");


    myData3.number = 110;
    myData3.name = "righty";
    addBSTree(tree, &myData3);

    //check the position of the third element that is added to the BST tree    
    if (compare(tree->root->right->val, (TYPE *) &myData3) != 0) {
        printf("addNode() test: FAIL to insert 110 as right child of root\n");
        return;
    }
    else if (tree->cnt != 3) {
        printf("addNode() test: FAIL to increase count when inserting 110 as right of root\n");
        return;
    }
    else printf("addNode() test: PASS when adding 110 as right of root\n");


    myData4.number = 10;
    myData4.name = "righty of lefty";
    addBSTree(tree, &myData4);

    //check the position of the fourth element that is added to the BST tree
    if (compare(tree->root->left->left->val, (TYPE *) &myData4) != 0) {
        printf("addNode() test: FAIL to insert 10 as left child of left of root\n");
        return;
    }
    else if (tree->cnt != 4) {
        printf("addNode() test: FAIL to increase count when inserting 10 as left of left of root\n");
        return;
    }
    else printf("addNode() test: PASS when adding 10 as left of left of root\n");
}
```

Comment: Add the code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you replace `if(val < cur->val)  {` with such as `if(compare(val, cur->val)<0) {` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I added in code that I'm using to test this function.  It breaks on test 3.

Comment: Yeah, we must have test code. but again , Did you replace `if(val < cur->val) {` of part of `_addNode` with using `compare` function ?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should avoid using names that start with an underscore in code you write — such names are reserved for use by the implementation.  The full specification is a bit more nuanced (it's section 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers in the C99 or C11 standard), but "don't use leading underscores" is safe (it will never get you into trouble) whereas using leading underscores might get you into trouble.  (It is unlikely to be the immediate cause of your problem, though.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY No I did not.

Comment: There is a need to replace the parts of your comparing. then test again.

Comment: I still run into the same issue if I do that.

Comment: Did you replace `else if(val > cur->val) {` too? **Add** (not modify) what changes did you make changes to the post.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, yup I missed the second one.  This fixed the problem.